# Do I need NAT gateway to access external elb from lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, elastic-load-balancer

I have database which is not exposed to public(running in ec2 instance which is in vpc). I have web-app running on ec2 which connects to database. I expose this web-app via application load balancer which also resides in vpc.

I want to access database as well call api in web-app from lambda function. To enable first connection I have setup lambda inside vpc and given security groups.

Do I need to setup NAT gateway(which is expensive) to access web-app via load balancer. I am aware that if lambda is inside vpc, it needs NAT gateway setup to call external services, However elb is not external resource.

Currently I am not able to access elb from lambda. My setup is as follows

ELB

meteor-app(application load balancer internet facing) (security groups: sg-6141c009, sg-edd58d86) in vpc vpc-1bedde72

Lambda

vpc: vpc-1bedde72, security groups: sg-0c53aa67, role: prod(with full EC2 access)

sg-0c53aa67 (on lambda) - no inbound rules

outbound rules:
all traffic at all ports to any destination,
TCP on port 443 at sg-6141c009

sg-6141c009(on elb)

inbound:
https traffic from any source

outbound
all traffic to any destination

Comment: Have you tried it? Was your lambda not able to call ELB? Are you asking Yes/No question or you actually have a problem here?

Comment: Yes actually it was not working, sorry my bad.

Comment: what was the error you were getting?

Comment: Lambda gets stuck on making request. I do not get any callback for response, then lambda kills my process after timeout. If I remove it from vpc, I get response, however i wont be able to connect to my db.

Comment: What your ELB Security Group looks like for Inbound connection?

Comment: I have edited question to include my setup. Sorry for bad formatting!

Comment: *"elb is not external resource"*... unless it is an internal-only ELB (an option you can select when the ELB is created) then yes, it **is** an external resource.

Comment: that means if ELB is not internal-only, lambda in vpc needs NAT gateway setup to call elb urls.

Comment: are you able to solve the issue? I'm facing the same issue. I can't call API through ELB. in my case, I already gave Nat instance to lambda still it is not working.

Comment: We were not able to solve it without using NAT gateway, and we have not created NAT gateway as well. As a temporary solution we opened the port to external services.